# Metadata file 'C:\Dev\Repositories\<repo>\<ProjectName>\obj\x86\Debug\net5.0\ref\<ProjectName>.dll' could not be found

Tags: c#, msbuild, .net-assembly, .net-5, visual-studio-2022

I have a problem with Visual Studio build since it looks for reference assemblies and cannot find them. The ref folders exist but they are empty.

I have several projects within my solution and I get this error for almost all of them, but not so long ago it could build the solution perfectly. I don't know what's changed, I didn't do any changes in .csproj files or .sln.

There exists a Jenkins pipeline for this whole product and it works, so I think the problem is in my computer, somewhere... I checked on remote desktop that on the machine that Jenkins builds on the reference assemblies are created as they should be.

Has anybody met with this issue?

Comment: Where did the dll you refer to come from?  Check if it is compatible with your project's framework. Does there any other folder in obj\x86\Debug? Maybe you can try to delete bin and obj folder and rebuild the project. Make sure you don't have any other error messages in your project and if you do, fix those first.

Comment: @pedro, what about this issue? If it worked well before, how about create a blank solution and cope them to the new solution which are in the default project folder like C drive? Please run vs as the admin check it again. Also make sure that you have the read permission for the specific folder in your PC. If not help, I suggest you build your projects one by one and check the detailed output messages. You could unload other project firsts and debug one by one.

Comment: Actually the real problem was that VS started to use a different NuGet config (due to a branch switch) and I didn't notice and the error log wasn't so helpful.